# Test Email Deliverability not working

Tags: apex, email, apex-email-service, debug, deliverability

I am working in Apex email services. I encountered that the email is not delivering. Therefore I checked the Test email deliverability which was also not working.

Checked the deliverability in our Sandbox
[image]

Performed all the troubleshoot as per the doc. But no luck.
I also wonder if there is any limit that is not allowing for the email not delivering.

Any chance what should be the issue. Is there anyway I can debug?

Comment: Have you checked the Email Logs feature in Setup? It can show you what emails should have been sent.

Comment: yes, it showed me as sent. But I did not receive those.